# JavaScript pulldown menu for adding tags to question in Stack Overflow not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, javascript, internet-explorer-9

I am using Internet Explorer 9 and have found, when asking a question, the JavaScript pulldown menu for adding tags to a question in Stack Overflow is not working?

Comment: Posted question using Chrome...

Comment: I would think the proper place to report this would be to the IE9 team, not the StackOverflow team.

Comment: @Mark - depends on where the problem is. If its because the JS is treating IE9 like one of its bastard predicessors and not like the kinder, more standards-compliant browser it is trying to become - its a site issue. If its becase the IE team munged up the JS engine somehow, then its their problem.

Comment: FWIW, while I somewhat agree with not supporting beta browsers, marking all bugs as [status-declined] instead of [status-deferred] bothers me in some way I have not yet defined... maybe it has something to do with wondering what bugs will still remain when IE9 goes gold.

Answer (score 6):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Let me add a little clarification here: Most [internet-explorer-9](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-9) bug reports here on meta currently have a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag, and this has been interpreted by some to mean "Shut up, we don't give a §$%&."

But of course IE9 will be considered a supported browser once it comes out, and we will revisit (and, as you see here, have already started revisiting) all these bug reports.

Chances are that some of these bugs are still around when IE9 comes out. This particular case, for example, was a jQuery plugin that failed badly at user agent sniffing, so this was indeed not an IE9 bug; just another proof that user agent sniffing is at best dangerous (even if, unfortunately, not always avoidable).

What we want to make clear with that tag is the following: Currently, using IE9 (or Chrome 10, or Firefox 4) is considered unsupported, so these bugs have a low priority for us. Making the sites work in released browsers comes first. If you're using a pre-release browser, expect some weirdnesses.

But we still appreciate that users are testing our sites in these browsers and make us aware of potential problems in advance.  And you can be sure that sooner or later, most [internet-explorer-9](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-9) bugs will be either [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: I wish I could pin this.

Answer (score 5):

Beta browsers are not supported by the Stack Overflow team.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: While true, this is no longer "correct."