# Broken reputation chart with IE9 in Area51

Tags: bug, area-51, reputation-graph, internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation graph doesn't work in IE 9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/reputation-graph-doesnt-work-in-ie-9)

In Area51, when browsing with IE9, the reputation tab on the user page does not display the chart.  I can work around the issue by clicking the compatibility view button or manually switching to IE8 mode.  Stackoverflow doesn't seem to have the same issue.

Comment: I usually try to avoid being redundant.  In this case, I can express the issue using tags alone.  The redundant title and the body are just for completeness.  :)

Comment: FYI: IE9 isn't final, so it [isn't supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66680/problems-with-ie9-beta-rc/66708#66708) and is [low priority](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65081/javascript-pulldown-menu-for-adding-tags-to-question-in-stack-overflow-not-workin/79565#79565). Expect some weirdness until it hits release.

Comment: This is a silly policy. And worse, it is implemented poorly. If your policy is to not support above a certain version of IE, assert that policy by using the X-UA-Compatible meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`. But shouldn't a popular, cutting edge website who's primary audience is developers support the browsers that developers are using?

Comment: It's not that we don't support certain versions of browsers (though we won't go out of our way for IE6 for example)...it's that we don't fix bugs in BETA browsers, since it's most likely *not our bug*. If we chase down a work-around when it works in *every other browser* and then the beta-browser fixes it before release...well we've just wasted a lot of time for nothing.  I *totally* disagree it's a silly policy, it's quite practical.  There are better uses of development time than fixing a moving, incomplete target :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed IE9 on my VM and this is the same problem.
 The couse is that the SE sites do not suppport Beta browsers at the momment.